# Warning! Unknown device API version

Tags: android

I am new to Android programming. I have created an app and I am deploying it on my Android device with version 4.0.3. I have connected the device properly. Even though I get this warning, I have deployed successfully on previous occasions. I am really not able to understand why my device version is not getting detected now.

Has my device cable gotten loose? How can I fix this?

Comment: Plug usb cable out and put it back in

Comment: The problem can be caused by the Device, So the solution is to restart it

Comment: In my case, I had to enable the Internet on the Android emulator... (was disabled in the top drawer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

first reset adb from device in eclipse and also check below things
(in ddms go device (look like small mob logo and reset adb)

hope at least one of the following will help:

You have to uninstall the application from the application manager on your cellphone before you can install it again.
Also check the version compatibilty issue
Apparently, your device is not properl connected

nd also make

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
```

in androidmainfest.xml

Comment: Yep. I also found that simply closing Eclipse, disconnecting the device and then re-connecting it, and then re-starting Eclipse worked as well.